# wgetでダンロードしたデータはどこに保存される？

Tags: macos, wget

当方macbookでwgetコマンドについて学ぶ機会がありました。

引数にURLを指定するとそのコンテンツがダンロードすることができるとあり、実際にいくつかのサイトをスクレイピングしましたが**特に保存先のディレクトリを指定しない場合、ダンロードしたデータについてはどこに保存される**のでしょうか。

また、**ダウンロードしたデータを一括で削除する方法**がありましたらそちらも合わせてご教示いただければ幸いです。

伺いたい２つの項目を体系的に説明しているサイトを見つけることができませんでした。

非常に常識的な質問かもしれませんが、お答えいただきたいです。
どうぞよろしくおねがいします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

保存先を指定しなければ、コマンドを実行したカレントディレクトリにファイルが保存されるはずです。

また、"wgetで保存したファイル" のような履歴情報は残らないので、判別可能なように保存先を分けてダウンロードするか、予めダウンロードリストを作成しておきダウンロード・削除を実行するなどの工夫が必要かと思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
削除をしっかりと見据えるならばファイル名も指定して実行する必要があるのですね。
重ねて質問して大変申し訳ありません。カレントディレクトリレントディレクトリを閉じてしまって探し方がわからないときは、どのようにすればよいでしょうか。

Comment: 「閉じてしまって分からない」だけでは wget とは直接関係がありませんし、ファイル名などのヒントがないと第三者は判断できません。もう一度ダウンロードし直すなどの対応を行ってみて下さい。